# CakePHP: Keeping a "View" count

Tags: cakephp

I have a "Coupon" controller. The index() function grabs a handful of coupons in each category and display them (ie):

```
public function index() {
    $showPerPage = 4;

    $this->Coupon->recursive = 0;

    $this->set('restaurants', $this->Coupon->findAllBycategory_id('1', '', '', $showPerPage));
    $this->set('entertainment', $this->Coupon->findAllBycategory_id('2', '', '', $showPerPage));
    $this->set('spas', $this->Coupon->findAllBycategory_id('3', '', '', $showPerPage));
    $this->set('services', $this->Coupon->findAllBycategory_id('4', '', '', $showPerPage));
    $this->set('hotels', $this->Coupon->findAllBycategory_id('5', '', '', $showPerPage));
    $this->set('retail', $this->Coupon->findAllBycategory_id('6', '', '', $showPerPage));
}
```

For each array set (restaurants, entertinamnent, spas, etc), I want to filter through *each* coupon and increase their "mini_views" counter to 1. I've created a function in the model called "increaseMiniView($id)". What's the best way to handle this? I know I can just foreach through each one, but I didn't know if there was a better way (I could also place the code in the view, but I know that's the best way either)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do something like this:

```
$restaurants = $this->Coupon->findAllBycategory_id('1', '', '', $showPerPage);
foreach($restaurants['Coupon'] as $restaurant) 
    $couponId[] = $restaurant['id'];

$entertainments = $this->Coupon->findAllBycategory_id('2', '', '', $showPerPage);
foreach($entertainments['Coupon'] as $entertainment) 
    $couponId[] = $entertainment['id'];    

// ... repeat for all queries

$this->Coupon->updateAll(
    array('Coupon.count' => 'Coupon.count+1'),
    array('Coupon.id' => $couponId)
);

$this->set(compact('restaurants', 'entertainments'));
```

[Complex Find Conditions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#complex-find-conditions) and [updateAll](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-updateall-array-fields-array-conditions).

Store all coupon id's in an array and pass them trough to the updateAll method in which you could update any field you want.

Good luck!

Comment: Exactly. You could also delegate the loops to `Set::extract`.